# Can't update table 'table2' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following tables

```
create table table1(
`Aid` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
`A` int NOT NULL,
`B` int NOT NULL,
primary key(Aid)
);

create table table2(
`Bid` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
`C` int NOT NULL,
`D` int NOT NULL,
primary key(Bid)
);

create table table3(
`ABid` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
`E` int NOT NULL,
`F` int NOT NULL,
`G` int NOT NULL,
`H` int NOT NULL,
primary key(ABid)
);
```

And I have the trigger

```
delimiter //

create trigger addrecords
after insert on table2
for each row
begin
  insert into table3(E,F,G,H) select a.Aid,b.Bid,b.C,b.D from table1 a,table2 b;
END; //
```

Upto this it is fine, but there is problem with following trigger

```
delimiter //

create trigger delrecords
after insert on table3
for each row
begin
  delete from table2;
END; //
```

When a row is inserted into `table2`, then the trigger will be called, and after that I want to delete all the records from the `table2` so that for the next insert into `table2` it should be empty.

Comment: There's no way round this,,

Comment: is there any way to get the latest record which is inserted in table2  such that it can be directly accessed and store in table3 , If I'm not clearing the rows in the table2 the problem I'm facing is there will be duplicate rows such that for every insertion in table2 the trigger will insert the rows which are already inserted previously. is there any way to get the latest record so that to avoid duplications?